# How to render a nested array of React components

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-dom

I am trying to render a nested array of React components. My example is this: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-brahmagupta-19dx4?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const components = [
    [<div>1A</div>, <div>1B</div>],
    [<div>2A</div>, <div>2B</div>]
  ];

  return components;
}
```

That will print out:

```
1A
1B
2A
2B
```

But how do I print each array individually? For example, I want to print something like this:

```
LINE I
1A
2A

Line 2
2A
2B
```

~I'm also puzzled as to why I can't just do this: ~

Edit - This works!

```
{components.map((array) => {
  return array.map((item) => {
    return item;
  });
})}
```

Comment: Why would `forEach` return something? `map` returns something; perhaps you're confusing the two? But what you *seem* to want to do is actually zip the arrays together?

Comment: map doesnt work either

Comment: Define "doesn't work". I think you're having a fundamental misunderstanding about what you need to return, but also that your desired output is a zip, not a straight map.

Comment: Sorry. I got the examples mixed up in my previous comments. In your codesandbox, you forgot to return the result of `array.map()` (line 10 of `App.js`).

Comment: @Calvin Thank you! It works

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are trying to use a nested array.
But the reason for each div to be at one below other is by default div take parent width(in this case whole screen)
If you want to place div side by side, I love flex-box for that.

I modified your code as follow:-

```
  const rowFlex = {
       display: "flex"
   };


const components = [
    [
      <div style={rowFlex}>
        <div>1A</div>
        <div>1B</div>
      </div>
    ],
    [
      <div style={rowFlex}>
        <div>2A</div>
        <div>2B</div>
      </div>
    ]
  ];
```

so div 1A and 1B are inside a flex box (div with style flex)
you can now simple do

```
<div> {components} </div>
```

To answer your second question:-
you are right map should have worked (it does work). you are returning only from inner map func to outer map func but you need to return the value returned by inner map func from outer map as well.

like this:-

```
{components.map((array) => {
    return array.map((item) => {
      return item;
    });
  })}
```

Comment: sorry I missed the edited part where you have mentioned map worked